# What is wrong with my python hyperoperation recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, math

I tried to use the definition from Wikipedia for Hyperoperations and translate it into Python code.
My goal was to make it readable, making it fast was a task for later.
Here's the definition I used and below it is my code.
[image]

from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation#Definition

And now here's my code:

```
def hyperation(n, a, b):
    if n == 0:
        return b+1
    if n == 1 and b == 0:
        return a
    if n == 2 and b == 0:
        return 0
    if n >= 3 and b == 0:
        return 1
    return hyperation(n-1, a, hyperation(n, a, b-1))
```

When I tried it with hyperation(n=1, a=3, b=3), what should basically be the same as
3 + 3
I always hit the recursion limit, doesn't matter how high I set it.

When trying this on paper by hand, it works perfectly fine. And while debugging I couldn't figure out what happens.
Thanks for every help!!!

Comment: I would say it is a error somewhere else. I copy your function and execute it with print(hyperation(1,3,3)) and it works

Comment: Please don't edit your question in such a way as to invalidate the existing answers. Instead, you can ask a new question for a new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last line the `return` keyword is missing.

Comment: Wow thank you. While you're right and this was an error, it's still not working. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code was not formatted right, cause python is a indentation sensitive language.

Second, The last line of the error log indicates that the error is the addition of NoneType and int. You didn't return anything in the final `else` block, so that will return NoneType. Just add `return` at the beginning of the last sentence.

Third, you can delete every `elif` after `return` and just use `if`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the wrong identation was I typo I made only in StackOverflow. The missing return was actually a quiet dumb failure, but after correcting it, new problem is, as shown in the edited question, that my program does not come to an end and always reachs the recursion limit, no matter how high I set it. Anyway thanks for your help!